# Why I had error todo.views.signupuser didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

I write a site in django. And for some reason as a result I get an error `The view todo.views.signupuser didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`. How can I fix this error?

Below I will attach my code.

My html code:

```
signupupser.html
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<h2>{{ error }}</h2>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

My urls.py:

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signupuser, name='signupuser')
]
```

My views.py

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import IntegrityError

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form': UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': 'That Username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html',
                          {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': 'Passwords did not match'})
```

Comment: What if the user is created and no `IntegrityError` is raised? In that case your view does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

In case you make a *valid* POST request, and the user is created without rasing an `IntegrityError`, then the view does not return any `HttpResponse`.

For that case you need to return a HTTP response as well, likely a redirect to a URL to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get architectural pattern* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form': UserCreationForm()})
    else:
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html', {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': 'That Username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
            # ↓ cover this case
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
        else:
            return render(request, 'todo/signupuser.html',
                          {'form': UserCreationForm(), 'error': 'Passwords did not match'})
```